# cannot iterate through payload to get the desired output

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to the iterate through the payload, I want to get the desired output like `12|Yes&&13|Yes&&14|Yes&&15|Yes&&16|Yes&&17|Yes&&18|Yes&&19|Yes&&`.
I have tried to get in separate like `12|Yes&&` `13|Yes&&`. All I wanted is to concatenate `QId` and `Answer` before it saves to the database. How could I achieve this

`Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'` have to store each `Qid` and `answer` when the loop runs and append like desired output at the end and finally save it to database

browser payload

```
0: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 150…}
1: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "No", QId: 151…}
2: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 152…}
3: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 153…}
4: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "No", QId: 154…}
5: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "Yes", QId: 155…}
6: {AuditorId: 10, Agents: "Joshi", Supervisor: "Prabhu", TicketId: "HRR6506691",Answer: "No", QId: 156…}
```

Here, what I tried

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def SaveUserResponse(request):
   
  if request.method == 'POST': 
    
    data = []
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for ran in request.data:
        auditorid =ran.get('AuditorId')
        print('SaveUserResponse auditorid---', auditorid)
        ticketid = ran.get('TicketId')
        qid = ran.get('QId')
        answer = ran.get('Answer')
        sid =  ran.get('SID')
        print('sid--', sid)
        TicketType = ran.get('TicketType')
        TypeSelected = ran.get('TypeSelected')
        agents = ran.get('Agents')
        supervisor = ran.get('Supervisor')
        Comments = ran.get('Comments')
        action = ran.get('Action')
        subfunction = ran.get('AuditSubFunction')
        region = ran.get('AuditRegion')
        
        Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'
        for qid in Qstans:
          Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'
          print(Qstans)
        
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_SaveAuditResponse] @auditorid=%s,@agents=%s,@supervisor=%s,@ticketid=%s,@Qstans=%s,@sid=%s,@TicketType=%s,@TypeSelected=%s, @Comments =%s, @action=%s, @subfunction=%s, @region=%s',
         (auditorid,agents,supervisor,ticketid, Qstans,sid, TicketType, TypeSelected, Comments, action, subfunction,region))
        result_st = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in result_st:
            row = row[0]
    return Response({0:{'Status':row}})
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? You haven't told us. Do you get an error message? An incorrect result? Something else?

Comment: In database it's just saving only one question and answer not the entire one all I just want to save the entire answer `12|Yes&&13|Yes&&14|Yes&&15|Yes&&16|Yes&&17|Yes&&18|Yes&&19|Yes&&` to be saved. I have a made it to concatenate but still only one `Qid` and `Answer` is saving

Comment: I see a few possible issues in your code. You have `Qstans = str(qid)+'|'+ answer+'&&'`, which sets `Qstans` to a string containing a single qid and answer, and then for some reason you iterate over `Qstans` (which will set `qid` to each character in `Qstans`) and do that same assignment over and over again. The loop does nothing other than leave `Qstans` containing an invalid `qid`. Later you have a loop `for row in result_st` and all that does each time is reassign `row` to take the first item from the row... and then does nothing with it.

Comment: I think you need to work through your code line by line and think about what it's doing and why.